# Scribus file opening error

Tags: parsing, scribus

I have been editing a document and saving it with same file name a few times. My latest attempt to reopen generate a parsing error: namely lline 141, column 52. The file did not open. 
Is there a way to open the file?
Thanks for your help!!
Dan

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you see (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).  You'll probably need to show a (short) input file that produces the problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue with a Scribus file, it's very likely that it can be solved by looking with a text editor at its content.

But there is no way to tell you what the problem is, without having a look at the file itself.

If you can share the `.sla` file, you should upload to a file sharing platform and put a link to in the question.

An alternative is to open a ticket on https://bugs.scribus.net and upload there your file. If you mark the ticket as private, only the developers will be able to see your file.

I don't think that Statckoverflow has a way to share private messages with other users, so you cannot directly find a way to send me the file... but if should not be that hard to find one of my email addresses if you look for my name and Scribus.